# Find and replace json in a file using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am new at using jq and could use help with the following...

In essence, I am trying to "find and replace" a block of json in a file using a bash script.

I have a file called docs.json to where I retrieved a set of doc entries:

```
{
    "number_of_docs": "1000",
    "docs": [{
    {
        "_id": "000001",
        "_rev": "0",
        "_content": "abcdefg"
    },
    {
        "_id": "000002",
        "_rev": "0",
        "_content": "hijklmn",
        "_attachments": {
            "image1.png": {
                "content_type": "image/png"
                ...
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "000003",
        "_rev": "0",
        "_content": "opqrstuv"
    }]
}
```

And I'm trying to replace all the doc entries (the entire block, not just the value of the keys) that have "_attachments" with a new block of json that is stored in a variable named "doc":

```
{
    "_id": "000002_masked",
    "_rev": "0",
    "_content": "[Document content has been masked for confidentiality.]",
    "_attachments": {
        "confidential.png": {
            "content_type": "image/png"
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible with jq and running from within a bash script?

Thank you for the help and tips, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to select the documents that have the `_attachments` key, then replace them with the `|=` operator.

```
jq --argjson new "$doc" '(.docs[]| select(has("_attachments"))) |= $new' docs.json
```

`--argjson` is used to pass the value of `$doc` into the filter as a raw JSON value.

Comment: Thank you! @chepner. Worked perfectly. One note for future readers: --argjson is a jq 1.5 feature. Previous versions don't have arg.

Comment: Do you know what the syntax should be when invoking from within a bash script?. I've been getting "jq: error: Cannot iterate over null". Based on my reading, I'm thinking it's because of the piping or quotes, and the bash script getting confused with the jq syntax. Do you have any insights on this? Thanks!

Comment: The command above should work whether it appears in a script or typed at the command line; the error sounds related to the contents of the input file.

Comment: The command runs fine from the cli, and only gives the error when invoked from within the script. I'll have to look more into this.

Comment: What would be a 1.3 compatible alternative solution? The worker machine this will be running on only has version 1.3 (and updating could be a lengthy process).

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure, but it looks like if there is, it won't look much like this solution. There's no way you can upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `--argjson` you could use the `-s` slurp option along with a filter such as

```
  .[0] as $new
| .[1]
| ( .docs[] | select(has("_attachments")) ) = $new
```

if the above is in `filter.jq`, your new document in `new.json` and your data contains a single object as you describe in `docs.json` then

```
jq -M -s -f filter.jq new.json docs.json
```

will produce

```
{
  "number_of_docs": "1000",
  "docs": [
    {
      "_id": "000001",
      "_rev": "0",
      "_content": "abcdefg"
    },
    {
      "_id": "000002_masked",
      "_rev": "0",
      "_content": "[Document content has been masked for confidentiality.]",
      "_attachments": {
        "confidential.png": {
          "content_type": "image/png"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "000003",
      "_rev": "0",
      "_content": "opqrstuv"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note - I don't have jq-1.3 so I'm only able to verify this with jq-1.5 but I believe this should work with jq-1.3